# How can I create a Timer that it can work even when the app is closed in android

Tags: android

I wrote the following code and it is a Timer. But it has a problem and its problem is that when I close the app, also the count operations stops. But I want to continue the count operations, even when I close the application.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button startButton;
    private Button pauseButton;
    private TextView timerValue;
    private long startTime = 0L;
    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
            }
        });pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);
        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
            }
        });
    }
    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {



        public void run() {
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have did it too. It depends on your requirement but there are 2 possibilities I have met with. But there could be more.

1. You can Use Alarm Manager
2. You can use simple timer in the service (which is not so good)

So I think these things will help , I would attach the link of source code if you would ask .

Comment: if you want to make your timer working even you app is exit then The Service is best possible way as far as I know

Answer (score -1):

Wait, do you mean completely closed or in a pause state?

Basically if you want your app to be closed you can just a create a service, otherwise if you mean that is into the pause state, your code will work perfectly.

Comment: Not really a valid answer? More like a comment

Comment: Yes I haven't reputation yet to add comments in a Post that's why I added. Sorry about that

Comment: No worries. Annoying that you can post answers before comments :)